# Flutter Delete Field in Array in Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

After getting the same data, I want to delete a specific field in the Array inside a document

[image]

[Execution][2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir687.jpg

my code

```
deleteItemToCart(String? foodItemId, BuildContext context, int quantity)
{
  String itemID = foodItemId!+ ":$quantity";
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
      .update({
    'userCart.$itemID' : FieldValue.delete(),
  }).then((value)
  {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Item Added Successfully.");

    print("ItemID " + itemID);

    //update the badge
    Provider.of<CartItemCounter>(context, listen: false).displayCartListItemsNumber();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete an item from an array, you'll want to use `FieldValue.arrayRemove` operator as shown in the documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

If I have if correctly, that'd be:

```
.update({
  'userCart' : FieldValue.arrayRemove([itemID]),
})
```

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'. Thank you for your response

Comment: What data type should I use for my ItemID?

Comment: `itemID` should be the exact same value you have in the `userCart` array. Ah, from the documentation (that I conveniently linked) it should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(docId)

.update({

'ArrayName': FieldValue.arrayRemove([your field Name here between brackets])

});